# Jmeter Distributed Environment : Active Threads Over Time : total not displayed

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter distributed environment (localhost and host1)
localhost (master and slave)
host1 (slave).

I have a thread group in my test plan with **10 users** and **50 loops**.

Running the test as bellow :

> jmeter.bat -t myscript.jmx -n -r -l results.csv

My test runs successfully and I get a total of 20 threads as displayed on the output

`summary + 800 in 30,2s = 26,5/s Avg: 580 Min: 33 Max:  2315 Err: 0 (0,00%) Active: 20 Started: 20 Finished: 0`

But when I try to graph **"jp@gc - Active Threads Over Time"** with data in results.CSV , I just get the **number of active threads = 10** .

**My question is how can I get a Grape with all 20 threads running?**

The main problem is that I suspect that  result.csv is not complete and does not contain all performance information such as **response time** etc.

Comment: Is that the final output from the test? In that case your test was not finished successfully as it is showing 
`Active: 20 Started: 20 Finished: 0`.

 If the test was finished successfully then `Finished:  20` would appear in the output.

Comment: From the Documentation: JMeter Plugins::Active Threads Over Time Listener  `If you are doing distributed tests, you should name the thread groups like this in your test plan: ${__machineName()}_My Threadgroup name`

Answer (score 0):

**For JMeter version < 5.0 :**

This is because you need to add a unique ID per injector in Thread Group name as per documentation:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/

For example:

If running only 1 JMeter per machine:

> ${__machineName()}_My Threadgroup name

If running multiple injectors per machine::

> ${__P(JVM_ID,1)}_My Threadgroup name

**For version >= JMETER 5.0:**

It will work correctly Out Of The Box as per this fix:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62684